# Removing "String" element from a Priority Queue inside DefaultTableModel in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, defaulttablemodel

This is my first time working with Queues, and I am experiencing difficulties when trying to remove an element of type String from a Priority Queue in a DefaultTableModel in Java. At first I've started to receive an exception, but after changing my code, all I get is nothing. Could someone please, help me pointing me at the right way if possible?

Here is how my code looks.

This is my class:

```
    public class nameQueue
{
    private Queue<String> nQueue;
    private int rows;

    public nameQueue(int r)
    {
        nQueue=new PriorityQueue<String>();
        this.rows=r;
    }

    public void generateNames()
    {
        String[] names= {"Erick", "Christian", "Lukas", "Albert", "Abel"};

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
        {
            nQueue.offer(names[rnd.nextInt(4)]);
        }
    }

    public String removeNames()
    {
        return nQueue.remove();
    }

    public Queue<String> getnQueue()
    {
        return nQueue;
    }

    public void setnQueue(Queue<String> nQueue)
    {
        this.nQueue=nQueue;
    }

    public int getrows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setrows(int row)
    {
        this.rows=row;
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       int option=this.jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
       int rows = Integer.parseInt(this.jTextField1.getText());
       nameQueue names = new nameQueue(rows);
       DefaultTableModel mod = new DefaultTableModel();

       switch(option)
       {
            case 1:
            {
               //Generating the names and putting them on the table. Works as intended
                names.generateNames();

                Iterator itr = names.getnQueue().iterator();

                mod.setRowCount(rows);
                mod.setColumnCount(1); 
        //Don't know if necessary, but since it's only one I leave it as that.

                int i =0;
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    mod.setValueAt(itr.next(), i, 0);
                    i++;
                }
                this.jTable1.setModel(mod);                
            }break;

            case 2:
            {
                //Here we attempt to remove the data following the FIFO rule
                String data = names.getnQueue().peek();
                for (int i = 0; i < mod.getRowCount(); i++) 
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < mod.getColumnCount(); c++) 
                    {
                        if(i<mod.getRowCount())
                        {
                            if(mod.getValueAt(i, c).equals(data))
                                    {
                                      names.removeNames();
                                      mod.removeRow(i);
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you try to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - a class like `nameQueue` should not start with lowercase.

Comment: Why, of course! I appreciate so much the observation and will consider it on further projects/questions.

Comment: How does your code even compile? You have a call to `nQueue.remove()` without any parameter. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html, `remove()` requires you to pass a reference to the object to be removed. Also, your `generateNames` method will never add "Abel" to the queue because the upper bound of `nextInt` is exclusive. And it's highly likely to generate duplicates.

Comment: The logic in your code is confusing enough that I have at best a vague idea of what you're trying to do. Please explain, *in words,* what your program is supposed to be doing. Perhaps then somebody can help you with your logic.

Comment: I should've been clearer then. Thank you and please allow me to explain myself:

What I'm trying to achieve here is to create a simple program that will store names inserted by an user in a PriorityQueue, and will latter show them in a table. (For this I'm using a DefaultTableModel)
For testing purposes I'm using randomly" generated names, and it works as intended.

But, depending on the option selected from the cbox (Case 2), I want as well that the user can remove names from both the model and the queue FOLLOWING the FIFO rule.

Comment: If you want to remove something from the queue, call `nQueue.poll()`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html